# Курсор в SQL

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте) Разбираюсь с курсором, вроде создал, выдает то, что нужно.

```
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR LOCAL DYNAMIC SCROLL
    FOR SELECT ID from Table1 where Name='стандарт'
OPEN cursor1

declare @id int
declare @a int

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 into @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
print @id
FETCH NEXT FROM post_cursor into @id
END
close cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1
```

В результате мне выдаются ВСЕ записи удовлетворяющие этому запросу. Мне нужно чтобы эти записи выдавались по одной (нажимаю я вызов, мне выводится одна запись, нажимаю еще раз вызов-выводится другая и т.д., произвольно в общем). Как это сделать в данной ситуации? Если создавать еще одну переменную и присваивать ей [[[[[@id](/users/3123/idanil)](/users/3123/idanil)](/users/3123/idanil)](/users/3123/idanil)](/users/3123/idanil) где-то за курсором, то выводится только последняя запись((( Надеюсь понятно объяснил)

Comment: Что за синтаксис? :-) Хоть бы тег проставили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При вызове у вас создается курсор и разрушается. Вы не можете перемещаться по нему между вызовами. Выбирайте строки непосредственно из таблицы случайным образом.
Если я правильно понял замысел, то проблему решает такой запрос:

```
SELECT top 1 @id = ID from Table1 where Name='стандарт'
order by NEWID()
```

Comment: можно как-то подробнее? курсор вообще не подойдет что ли?

Comment: @StyleS, а Вы не указали, что Вы с этим курсором делать собираетесь. Только это вопрос уже не имеет отношения к sql. Хотя, возможно, я только по неграмотности не знаю, что в sql означает "нажать вызов"

Comment: >  курсор вообще не подойдет что ли?

Я думаю, да. Помнится Дж.Селко писал, что он за всю свою жизнь использовал курсор раз 5, и это число уменьшилось бы до 2, если бы в то время существовали все то новое, что появилось в SQL. :-)